# How does one make sure that the parameters are update manually in pytorch using modules?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, pytorch

I wanted to update the parameters of a model manually with pytorch. I made a super simple standard sequential model ([full code here](https://github.com/brando90/simple_regression/blob/master/minimum_example.py)) but whenever I try to train my model it does not train unless I create the actual variables explicitly ([code for model variables explicitly](https://github.com/brando90/simple_regression/blob/master/direct_example.py)). So with the sequential model the code looks as follow:

```
mdl_sgd = torch.nn.Sequential( torch.nn.Linear(D_sgd,1,bias=False) )
...
for i in range(nb_iter):
    # Forward pass: compute predicted Y using operations on Variables
    batch_xs, batch_ys = get_batch2(X,Y,M,dtype) # [M, D], [M, 1]
    ## FORWARD PASS
    y_pred = mdl_sgd.forward(X)
    ## LOSS
    loss = (1/N)*(y_pred - batch_ys).pow(2).sum()
    ## Manually zero the gradients after updating weights
    mdl_sgd.zero_grad()
    ## BACKARD PASS
    loss.backward() # Use autograd to compute the backward pass. Now w will have gradients
    ## SGD update
    for W in mdl_sgd.parameters():
        #print(W.grad.data)
        W.data = W.data - eta*W.grad.data
```

when I train it it seems that nothing happens. I've tried many things to make this work like wrapping it in a class and putting explicit `require_grads=True` or change the locations where I make the zero out the gradients etc but nothing seems to work. What I really want/need is to be able to explicitly be able to do the update rule **myself** (not with optimum). Not sure if thats the reason it doesn't work but the following **does work** for some reason:

```
X = poly_kernel_matrix(x_true,Degree_mdl) # maps to the feature space of the model
X = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(X).type(dtype), requires_grad=False)
Y = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(Y).type(dtype), requires_grad=False)
w_init=torch.randn(D_sgd,1).type(dtype)
W = Variable( w_init, requires_grad=True)
...
for i in range(nb_iter):
        # Forward pass: compute predicted Y using operations on Variables
        batch_xs, batch_ys = get_batch2(X,Y,M,dtype) # [M, D], [M, 1]
        ## FORWARD PASS
        #y_pred = mdl_sgd.forward(X)
        y_pred = batch_xs.mm(W)
        ## LOSS
        loss = (1/N)*(y_pred - batch_ys).pow(2).sum()
        ## BACKARD PASS
        loss.backward() # Use autograd to compute the backward pass. Now w will have gradients
        ## SGD update
        W.data = W.data - eta*W.grad.data
        ## Manually zero the gradients after updating weights
        #mdl_sgd.zero_grad()
        W.grad.data.zero_()
```

the reason I know this is because the plot of the regression lines look sensible:

[image]

while when I use the `torch.nn.Sequential` I get:

[image]

I am sure its a really newbie question but I am not sure why I can't update the parameters. Does someone know why? I want to be able to update the parameters manually (however I want) and in this case I decided to use SGD to see if I could even update the parameters.

---

Note I also tried subclassing modules and registering params but it didn't work either. This is the class I built:

class regression_NN(torch.nn.Module):

```
def __init__(self,w_init):
    """
    """
    super(type(self), self).__init__()
    # mdl
    #self.W = Variable(w_init, requires_grad=True)
    #self.W = torch.nn.Parameter( Variable(w_init, requires_grad=True) )
    #self.W = torch.nn.Parameter( w_init ) 
    self.W = torch.nn.Parameter( w_init,requires_grad=True )
    #self.mod_list = torch.nn.ModuleList([self.W])

def forward(self, x):
    """
    """
    y_pred = x.mm(self.W)
    return y_pred
```

---

All code is:

https://github.com/brando90/simple_regression

I'm relatively new at pytorch so I might have many bad practice...you can correct them if u want but Im mostly concerned that my paremters are not updating even when I try to explicitly register them in a class that inherits from `torch.nn.Module`.

---

I also linked to the question from the pytorch official forum: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-does-one-make-sure-that-the-parameters-are-update-manually-in-pytorch-using-modules/6076

Comment: not sure why the above doesn't work but `W.data = W.data - eta*W.grad.data` **should** work but `W = W - eta*W.grad` does not. Though I am not sure why that is the case...

Comment: best solution I know so far is to use `W.data.copy_(new_value.data)`